# Automatic file removal from server?

Tags: php, file, timestamp, delete-file

I was wondering if there was a way of using a script or some other option whereby I could automatically have files over a certain date deleted from my server.

I have created an AS3 eCard application whereby a php script writes a *.txt file to a folder with the relevant details of the message etc and would like to know if it's possible to have files over 'n' days old automatically deleted some way to avoid cluttering up the site?

**PHP Amendment :**

```
    <?php

if ($handle = opendir('/myFolder/holdingFolder')) {

while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
    $filelastmodified = filemtime($file);

    if((time() - $filelastmodified) > 14*24*3600)
    {
       unlink($file);
    }

}

closedir($handle); 
}
?>
```

I'm still learning php and would appreciate if anyone with more experience could look over this to point me in the right direction, if it's the right way to go about deleting files in a folder after 14 days of creation?

If so, my server is windows/Plesk, would I need any special commands to run it and how often would you advise?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have said, I think the easiest thing for you to get started with is a cron job and a php script.

Write a PHP script to loop the files checking creation date and delete the old ones. Then set up the PHP script on a cron job, which can run on any schedule you want.

There are of course 1000 ways to approach this, but it sounds like you already know PHP, and cron is available on any *nix system.

[Here is a link to a random Google result for Crontab info and usage.](http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll look into it now i know the name. I know it's possible as I've seen it implemented on other sites but when you've never done it before, not  knowing the techniques half the problem in finding it when you want to learn it.

Comment: I've just added some code which I think might be on the right track, if you get chance to have a look I'd appreciate any feedback as I don't want to accidentally delete every folder on my server every 14 days!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
$dir = '/path/to/files/';
$days = 3600 * 24 * 7; // 7 days
if($handle = opendir($dir)) {

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ( filemtime($dir.$file) <= time()-$days) {
           unlink($dir.$file);
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

then run this script via a cron

Comment: Thanks guys, +1 for the help just haven't enough points to add it yet being a noob, for reference, it's a windows server using Plesk so maybe the task scheduler can handle a similar command to the cron code above, if not I'll look into the php methods listed, out of curiosity which is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got access to cron, then you don't need PHP - e,g, to to once a day....

```
23 4 * * * find /your/directory -iname \*.txt -mtime +3 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

If you don't have access to cron, then run it as garbage collection as a shutdown function. E.g. (blatantly stealing Kyle Hudson's code, although I note that he even copied the comments [from here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) ;)

```
function gc_txt_files()
{
   $dir = '/path/to/files/';
   $days = 3600 * 24 * 7; // 7 days
   if($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
           if ( filemtime($dir.$file) <= time()-$days) {
              unlink($dir.$file);
           }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}
if (17==rand(0,200)) { // adjust 200 depending on how frequently you want to clear out
    register_shutdown_function('gc_txt_files');
}
```

Comment: Docs are all well and good but when you google things you're not so sure about and see 20 different ways to do them with little real difference explained or covered, it's often nice to hear from people who use them and know the subtleties or pro's and cons of differing ways. There are techniques and things people learning like myself miss out on due to so many different ways. I learn as much as I can where I can and enjoy the challenge of finding ways myself but am knew to php hence the query and am weary in using it with methods I'm unsure about, I'll risk it for a biscuit though... Θ)